# redirect a page from URL jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to redirect from a url. It works when I use `#!`, but I want to work with a parameter other than this.

```
//works
url = 'localhost/#!/about'
if (document.location.hash.replace(/^#?!\//, '') != '') {
    loadResource(true);
}


//doesn't work
url = 'localhost/about'
if(location.pathname.replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1') != ''){
    loadResource(true);
}
```

Why? Is there a way to not use `#!`?

Comment: It's hard to tell why it's not redirecting because there is nothing in your code that should make it redirect. What does the loadResources function do? Your previous example used `pathname.replace` which would probably not have worked, but is now been edited as `location.pathname`.

Answer (score 0):

The code above doesn't show any code for redirection. What does `loadResource` do?

Anyways, redirect in javascript is done like this:

```
// Syntax: document.location.href = url;
document.location.href = 'http://localhost/about';
```